# Why do I see a delete option under my answer (and how to find what's that about)?

Tags: support

I think [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1214566/925128) answer is not fit to be deleted, at least not compared to other answers under the same question ([Why is it that I am unable to format my pendrive in exfat using gparted?](https://askubuntu.com/q/771668/925128)) which received only answers that provide alternatives.

How could I find why was it voted for deletion?

---

Edit after comment saying **answers can only be down-voted**; I am posting a screenshot:

[image]

I am asking about the "delete" option — not about down-voting.

Comment: You can't close an answer, all it has is a downvote. As for why you were downvoted, who knows? Votes are anonymous. One downvote is not a big deal, don't let it get to you.

Comment: @MarkKirby - sorry: I meant "deleted", not "closed" .  I have edited the question and posted screenshot, I see the **delete** button there.  Is this a bug? The answer you linked is not about delete. Down-voting is not a mystery to me.

Comment: I don't see that for some reason, I thought I had the privilege to see delete votes. What that means is someone chose to recommend deletion from review. I can't find this in the review history for some reason. The only queue with answer delete votes is the low quality one, you can see the reviews here: https://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts/history?page=1

Comment: @MarkKirby - Maybe it's a "bug" of some kind that will go away. I do see it no matter what (switching browser, google account, IP).

Comment: I don't think it is a bug, you can see here: https://askubuntu.com/posts/1214566/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries that it did receive a delete vote sometime today. It is strange that I can't find the review in the history though.

Comment: @MarkKirby - what is odd it is that you don't see the delete option under my answer. When you said "you cannot close an answer" did you also meant "you cannot delete an answer"?

Comment: It seems that there is a further deletion privilege for 20k users https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/trusted-user and because that was used to vote for deletion I can't access the information about it. I did find the vote in the mod tools but it won't let me see it without 20k rep. I guess in this case all you can do is wait and see if the voter comments or if some 20k user can provide more information. For what it is worth, I would of voted to not delete your answer as I can find proof that software does work on Ubuntu 1/2

Comment: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/09/easily-format-usb-flash-drive-on-ubuntu.html but I guess my hands are tied here. 2/2

Comment: @MarkKirby - Thanks. You could up-vote my answer if you like it ;)

Comment: I did but I don't think that will effect the deletion votes.

Comment: @MarkKirby -  by the way, the bug mentioned in the posted link is not present anymore for `mintstick`

Comment: @sudodus - maybe the above question justifies an answer saying that 20k+ users can cast such delete votes, and that probably there is nothing else I can do (just like for down-votes), other than improve the post, and comment to ask for clarifications.

Comment: I can see vote summaries for today and yesterday, but it does not tell anything new to you. I agree with what @MarkKirby has already written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that [20k+ users can cast delete votes](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) on answer with a score of -1 or less.

If it is anonymous and no explanation why, you can

- ask for clarifications in a comment and
- try to improve the answer without spending too much effort.